# How to create an Outlook rule to assign a category to emails from contacts that have a specific category assigned?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, email-filter

How can I create an rule in Outlook which does the following when an email arrives:

1. Check if the sender is in my contacts
2. Check if the contact has a specific category (e.g. *Work*) assigned
3. Assign that (*Work*) or maybe some other category (e.g. *Important*) to the email

I've already accomplished 1 and 3 but I have no idea how to make 2 happen. Is it even possible?

Comment: Tried too but I could not find a way to do this. Check for a specific category of the mail, easy. Check for a specific category of the sended, no way, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I'm afraid there is no way to do this, the easier would be to create several Contacts folders, one per category.

Create a new folder (CTRL+SHIFT+E), indicating it will contain "Contact Items". Name it with the name of the category, "Contacts - Work" for instance. Create as many as needed.

[image]

Create as many rules as you have contacts folders, to assign the correct category to contacts for the specific contact folder.

[image]

Comment: Your contacts folder may not appear as an address book by default. In this case you'll need to go to the outlook address book tab in it's properties and check the box to make it show up. Also, rules that check address books and manipulate categories can only run on the client, not on an exchange server. Further rules that check address books will only run on one client and not on another that you might use to check the same mailbox. (Circa this writing).